# why Isn't my form working

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to use a listbox form to query the database but it's not showing anything. The idea is that I've queried the database to fill the form with the names of suburbs and then, selecting a suburb will query the database again to return the names of parks in that suburb. When I use the search form it doesn't return anything.

this is the form:

```
<p>Select Suburb to search</p>
    <form method="post" action="suburb_search.php" id="search">
    <select>
    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <option value="suburb"> <?php echo $row['suburb']?></option>
    <?php } 
     } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
    </form>
    </div>
```

This is where it should use the results of the form to query the database but its not working:

```
 <?php 
 $searchRequest = False;
if (isset($_GET['suburb'])){
    $search = $_GET['suburb'];
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM park_list WHERE suburb=$search";
    $result2 = $db->query($sql2);
if($message){
    echo "<p>$message</>";
} else {
    ?>
    <div class="form">
    <?php
        while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
    <div class="results">
    <h2><?php echo $row2['park_name'];?></h2> 
        <?php
    }
    } 
   } ?>
```

Comment: your query is vulnerable to SQL Injections `(suburb = $search)`

Comment: Your `select` element is missing the `name` attribute, so nothing will be send for it when you submit the form. And you likely do not want to output the same value for each option either - because that makes different selections pointless.

Comment: you seem to be basing yourself on the value, which is incorrect. The `<select>` should have the name attribute and the value being the row

Comment: `WHERE suburb=$search` I doubt that's an integer. And where is `$message` defined? and a few missing closing divs, unless that's not your full code.

Comment: @CBroe could you explain more please. I'm new to this so I don't know how to change the output for each option.

Comment: @Fred-ii- not my full code and $message is in an included file for database connection.

Comment: You managed to output different text content inside the options already, so you should be able to output different content inside the `value` attribute as well - right …? (And if not, you need to go learn some basics.)

Comment: @CBroe i see what you meant, sorry i was a bit confused

Comment: now it says "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\suburb_search.php on line 41" I swear everytime i fix one thing, the rest fall apart.

Answer (score 0):

give a name for your select element as

```
<select name="suburb">
    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <option value="suburb"> <?php echo $row['suburb']?></option>
    <?php } 
    } ?>
</select>
```

and you are giving form method as `POST` but accepting data in `GET` in your php code, change this

```
if (isset($_GET['suburb'])){
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['suburb'])){
```

Comment: welcome but I think you should look at their code again and there are a few comments under the question that you should look at

Comment: you got it to show the results from the table but its showing all of my park_name s not just for the suburb